# converting huge MPEG audio files to something smaller

Tags: conversion, audio, mp3, mpeg

I've got some large MPEG audio files (144 MB each) that I'm looking to convert to something smaller so I can send them out as attachments to an email. Any suggestions on the software to use? I'm looking for something free that will run on Windows. I don't really care what the destination file is, mp3 would be nice.

If there's a web service out there that would do this without the need to download any software to my machine, that would be even better, but I would be more than happy just getting it done any way I can. Thanks!

Comment: ffmpeg, but you have to specify the output format/bitrate I guess to appropriately shrink'em :)

Answer (score 0):

Online: http://www.zamzar.com/

Software: http://www.formatoz.com/